# multiple missing types from SAS to SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design, sas

I have a SAS dataset that I am converting to sql server 2005.  In the sas dataset there are numeric variables that allow for multiple missing values.

For example column AGE is specified as

0-124 = number
. = missing
.A = Invalid
.B = Unavailable

Now I want to use a number for the sql server datatype and need to maintain the integrity of the data.  My first thought is to create a reference table for the actual value from sas:

-1 = .A  = Invalid
-2 = .B  = Unavailable

This seems messy since age would require entry for each age 1-124.  Curious if anyone else has run across this and has a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that most of the time you're not going to care about why values are missing, just that they are missing - but by encoding it as negative integers, you'll have to be sure to filter those out every time you do anything with that variable.  That's backwards: you should do something special to incorporate the kind-of-missingness information, not to run basic math and statistics.

Rather than trying to recreate in SQL Server a data type that it doesn't have, why not work with what it's got?  I would probably just send the missing values as NULL to SQL Server and then encode the type of missingness in a second variable.  When you actually need to know why data are missing, it's still there; but when you don't, SQL Server will handle the missing values in your variable using its default methods for dealing with them.

Comment: You are correct, but there always is someone that wants to see the original data.  I am going to go with your thoughts of using NULL, then have a table that will map the multiple values of NULL so if needed the user can get the original data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a format to recode the missings to negatives while leaving the non-missings unchanged.

```
proc format;
  value chgmiss
    .=.
    .a=-1
    .b=-2
    .c=-3
;
run;

data a;
input original;
new=put(original, chgmiss3.);
put original=  new=;
datalines;
.
9
102
3
2
15
90
.a
.b
.
78
;
run;
```

Comment: This would be perfect but I have to maintain the integrity of the data, thus keeping the .A, .B and so on.  Thanks.